# In a Jupyter Notebook open in VS Code, how can I easily run a cell and advance to the next cell?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In VS Code, while working with Jupyter Notebooks, I am trying to run a cell and then advance to the next cell and keep the cursor in that cell. But after I advanced to the next cell, I have to click that cell to start writing my code. Is there any way to do that automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about Notebook editor, then I assume you're referring to the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut that is bound by default to the command `notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow`. And yes, it selects the next cell as a whole and does not move focus into the input editor section of the cell. You should be able to move focus into the cell by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If that's not good enough for you, you can put this in your keybindings.json file (open this file using `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in your [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
// option 1 (just pick one option. I'm pretty sure they're the same)
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow",
            "notebook.cell.edit",
        ],
    },
},
// option 2
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "notebook.cell.execute",
            "notebook.focusNextEditor",
        ],
    },
},
```

---

If you're talking about interactive windows and Python files with code cell magics, then either use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, which is bound to `jupyter.runcurrentcelladvance` by default, or use the `jupyter.interactiveWindow.textEditor.autoMoveToNextCell` setting if you want it to happen whenever you run a cell, regardless of whether you use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: nice! thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are in the **Command** mode when you run cell + advance. After advancing to the next cell, you need to go back to **Edit** mode. Instead of clicking the cell, you can just press *Enter*.

You can add your own shortcuts from `Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcuts`. But you can't create a shortcut where you can advance and also go to edit mode at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man it worked. I think after clicking enter it changed its default settings from Command mode to Edit mode.

Comment: "_you can't create a shortcut where you can advance and also go to edit mode at the same time_" - I beg to differ

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hit shift+enter instead of ctrl+enter.

ctrl + enter :
execute the current cell
shift + enter :
execute the current cell and go to the next cell at the same time